# SQLSTATE General Error 1005 Can't create table '#sql-3d63_ca5dc9' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have a Symfony CRM project using Doctrine that I'm currently moving over to a new server, the CRM hooks up to OpenCart 2.

A few of my tables have foreign keys that allow me to reference some of the OpenCart tables from my bespoke ones in my project, such as a product id to the product table and customer id to the customer table etc.

However, when I try to run `doctrine:schema:update --force` I get the following error:

> An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE project ADD
>   CONSTRAINT FK_2FB3D0EE4584665A FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES
>   oc73_product (product_id)':
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
>   'oc2017_myshop.#sql-3d63_ca5dc9' (errno: 150)

The two statements it throws this error on are as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE project ADD CONSTRAINT FK_2FB3D0EE4584665A FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES oc73_product (product_id);
ALTER TABLE project ADD CONSTRAINT FK_2FB3D0EEB18AFA7E FOREIGN KEY (stageName) REFERENCES stage (id);
```

I don't quite understand what the above error means, since I'm not creating a table called sql-3d63_ca5dc9? Can anyone shed any light on this?

If anymore info is needed in order to help with this let me know and I will include.

Comment: Table names starting with `#` are temporary tables.

Comment: Why would it be trying to create temporary tables? And how come it can't do it?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling us that a foreign key constraint isn't correctly formed.

Either there's a datatype mismatch of the foreign key column and the referenced column.

Or there's not an index defined on the referenced table with the referenced column as a leading column.

Or there's rows in the `project` table that don't match rows in the referenced table. That is, the `product_id` column contains values that don't appear in the  `oc73_product` table.

The error message doesn't distinguish between those possibilities; it's just telling us there's a problem with the foreign key.

---

The table name `#sql-3d63_ca5dc` is an intermediate name. MySQL will create a working copy of the table when the ALTER TABLE is running, and then will swap the name of the existing table onto the new copy.

---

For debugging this,

compare the datatypes of the `product_id` column in `project` and `oc73_product`

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE project ;
SHOW CREATE TABLE oc73_product ;
```

The datatypes have to be an *exact* match.

Verify that `oc73_product` has a KEY with `product_id` as the leading column. This can be the PRIMARY KEY, a UNIQUE KEY, or I think MySQL even lets you get away with just a KEY.

Verify that there are no rows in `project` that violate the constraint. There's rows that violate the foreign key constraint if this query returns any rows:

```
SELECT j.product_id
  FROM project j
  LEFT
  JOIN oc73_product d
    ON d.product_id = j.product_id
 WHERE d.product_id IS NULL
```

The result from the query using an anti-join pattern (above) is equivalent to the result from:

```
SELECT j.product_id
  FROM project j
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                      FROM oc73_product d
                     WHERE d.product_id = j.product_id
                  )
```

---

**FOLLOWUP**

As @Shadow mentions in a comment, the output of `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` may include a section like this:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2017-03-27 14:14:14 7fce73f9d700 Error in foreign key constraint creation
  for table `db`.`table_name`.
```

with details about the error condition that was encountered. The InnoDB engine knows more about the error than he is telling MySQL. MySQL is just reporting "InnoDB reported error 150", without any details of *why* InnoDB is reporting that error.

Comment: You could mention that you can get detailed description of the error using `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` statement

Comment: All the indexes seem to be in place - it was working before on the previous server, but it looks like it's just when it's trying to map to the new OpenCart tables. When I run SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS it just says Permission Denied....

Comment: MySQL user needs to be granted `PROCESS` privilege in order to execute `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`. (We are making an assumption here that the tables `project` and `oc73_product` are both InnoDB tables, i.e. `SHOW CREATE TABLE` shows `ENGINE=InnoDB`.)

Comment: I believe they are both InnoDB. When I run the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` commands, it truncates the response so I don't actually see the full result

Comment: We can get table info from information_schema.tables e.g. " `SELECT table_schema, table_name, table_type, engine from information_schema.tables where table_name in ('oc73_product','project')` ". We can get column info from information_schema.columns, and index info from information_schema.key_column_usage. (Also, we need to fix whatever "it" is that is truncating the results from SHOW CREATE TABLE. Or, we can use the mysql command line client. truncating return from SHOW CREATE TABLE shouldn't be a concern there.)